# Initializing a pointer with an absolute memory address

Tags: c, memory, operating-system, system-calls

I'm implementing a puts (print a string on screen) system call in a custom OS project I'm working on. The absolute memory address of the string is given to me by an `unsigned int` variable representing the `esi` register, and I need to initialize a pointer to an `unsigned char` array to read the string from.

The registers contents are represented by:

```
struct regs
{
    unsigned int gs, fs, es, ds;
    unsigned int edi, esi, ebp, esp, ebx, edx, ecx, eax;
    unsigned int int_no, err_code;
    unsigned int eip, cs, eflags, useresp, ss;
};
```

I have tried the following to initialize a pointer to the address in `esi`:

```
void fault_handler(struct regs *r) {
   void *p = (void*)r->esi;
   unsigned char* s = (unsigned char*)p;
   // take s and print it to the screen
}
```

But I don't get the "Hello\n" I'm supposed to get, instead I get garbage. I verified that the address of `esi` indeed points to the correct string. The problem I have is to initialize a pointer to this address.

Thanks!

Update: I will close this question and move the discussion to a new question as the original answer is answered. Thank you everyone!

Comment: are you sure about your printing module working correctly ?

Comment: Yes. When I load the program image to memory I printed the string correctly using the same code. So I'm certain the string is there and that printing works well.

Comment: Erm, so this fails when the program image is *not* loaded to memory.  What exactly might that mean?  You do normally have to have something in memory to make a pointer work.

Comment: @The Tuvias : "...I printed the string correctly using the same code" Er... But you just said that tis code doesn't work correctly. So does it work or not? If the code functionality depends on some other factors (sometimes works, sometimes doesn't), then maybe your should take a look at those other factors first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code correctly assigns esi to p and then s. Thus I can only assume your problem is not in fact related to this step.

As an aside I don't see why you need p, just assign esi directly to s.

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code is okay, and as @David Heffernan says, there is no use of the `p`. you can simply directly assign `esi` to `s`. You have checked the addresses, but please check the segment register value (real mode)/segment selector (protected mode), make sure that the segment register values are correct and the address in `esi` is used with the same segment when in the handler, and where you describe the string. Probably this will help.

Comment: In my syscall handler I get all register values and I see that ss is 0x1. If I understood your comment correctly, you suggest that I will check the value of ss when I load the string to memory. How do I check which segment selector is used there?

Comment: transfer the contents of the ss into memory and check, but i think you yourself had to assign the selector. How many segment selectors do you have set? And do they differ in memory range ?

Comment: I have 2 segments set - one for code and one for data, ranging from 0x0 to 0xFFFFFFFF. I checked cs,ds,es,fs and gs when my kernel loads the program image to memory and in my system call handler and they are the same. ss is different but I think that's OK as each task (the kernel and the user program) have different stacks, no?

Comment: the main point is that the the segment in which you stored the string with some address, you need to use that same segment and the offset address to fetch back the stored data, as after segmentation hardware will generate different physical addresses after the segmentation process for each different segment with the same offset value. In the case of sending some information from kernel space to user space, i think you should copy the information in user space and access the copied stuff in user space.

Comment: You say you have one code and one data segment each one covering the whole 4G memory, you tell that `ss` is different, and what different value does `ss` have ? Check which segment descriptor does the selector in `ss` selects.

Comment: When I load the program's elf image to memory cs=0x8 and ds,es,fs,gs,ss=0x10. When the program runs and executes a system call, inside the syscall handler cs=0x8 and ds,es,fs,gs=0x10 and ss=0x10d140.

Comment: It looks good, because the other segments point to the same one, but why `ss` points to a strange number, this might be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As others alrady noted, you can immediately initialize `s` with `r->esi`, without an intermediate variable `p`. The cast is needed though, so the initialization should look as `unsigned char* s = (unsigned char *) r->esi;`.

However, some things about your code raise faint suspicions. Register names look like names of 32-bit registers on x86 platform. Are your pointers 32 bit as well? I.e. are you compiling your code as 32-bit code?